# Plotting point every x m2 in polygon using QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, point, area, plot

I'm trying to work out whether its possible to plot a point every so often within a polygon.

For example, if I have a polygon thats 200x200m, perhaps I could plot a point at every meter squared within that polygon.

Are there any plugins that currently do this?

Comment: The solution depends on polygon's shape. If the polygon is like [that](http://s3.amazonaws.com/illustrativemathematics/images/000/002/759/medium/square1_f1b866a9f2093fcc8c2d29526190b822.jpg?1380838964) @MortenSickel's answer works. Thus, could you add a sample polygon? Do you need regular or random points at every 1 sqm?

Comment: Is it for visualisation of the polygon (like a point pattern), or do you need to run additional analysis based on the created points?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible and you do not need a plugin for it (Assuming you are using QGIS3)

Zoom to an area covering where you want the points

Then, Go to Vector -> Research tools -> Regular points

Set input extent to Use Canvas extent and set point spacing to 1
Press "Run"

You will probably get more points than you want / need, so for next step select the polygon you want to have the points in, 
Go to Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Clip

Select the newly created layer with the points as the input layer, Select the layer with your polygon as the Overlay layer, check Selected features only and "Run"

Just two details: You probably want to have your project in a meter based projection before doing this and if you do not save / make permanent your newly created layer, it will be gone when you close QGIS.

If you want to be able to display points in one or more polygons in your layer, first make the points over your entire layer, then for the second point use vector -> geoprocessing -> intersection using your newly created points and your polygon layer and you will get a new point layer with the attributes copied from the polygons.

Comment: If it's a rotated polygon like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqDpw.png), Using this solution does not guarantee that every 1 sq m area has a point.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution although its a little rough and ready - however works for any shape polygon which is what I needed.

Vector - research tools - regular points
Select input extent layer, set spacing interval etc...

Then once ran, clipped to points just within the polygon.